# Hypothesis Testing on Exponential distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent exponential $(\theta)$ random variables. Suppose we are interested in testing $H_0: \theta = \theta_0 = 1$ versus $H_A: \theta = \theta_1>1$. Consider two tests with rejection regions:

Test 1: {$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum^n_{j=1} x_j \geq k_{\alpha}$},

Test 2: {$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: X_{(1)} \geq h_{\alpha}$}.

> (1) For $n = 10$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, calculate $k_{\alpha}$.

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$ I believe that I should be able to apply the Nehman-Pearson Lemma to help me solve this since it is for a simple hypothesis test.  Knowing it is exponential family should also make some calculations a little easier.  Just stuck on the proper way of setting it up.

> (2) For $n = 10$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, calculate $h_{\alpha}$.

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$  Same idea as number (1), but again I am stuck on proper set-up.

> (3) Using the values found for $k_{\alpha}$ and $h_{\alpha}$, calculate the power of both tests with $\theta =2, 3, 4$. Based on the results of these findings, which test should be used?

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$  I think this may require a bit more work but I will just need to set it up according to the cases of the values for $\theta$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sum of the $X_i$ has Erlang distribution. There is an explicit cdf, but it is a little messy. However, particularly with root-finding software, you can find the $k$. The $h$ is somewhat easier, since the minimum of the $X_i$ has a nice distribution.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X_{(1)}$ if I may ask? Because I'm not getting anything nice/easily recognizable. I have $f(X_{(1)}) = \frac{n}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}(1-\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}})^{n-1}$

Comment: Would it be easier to do something with a power function?

Comment: $X_{(1)} = $ minimum has an exponential distribution

Comment: Is that from putting in $n=1$ to get $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-1}{\theta}}$?  Is it similar for setting up the distribution for Test 1?

Comment: Wouldn't $\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$ also be a Gamma?

Comment: Yes it would be Gamma. But with what values as $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Presumably $\alpha = n$ while $\beta=\theta$ or $\beta=\frac1{\theta}$ depending on whether you are talking about rates or means